# Xamarin not compiling in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I am trying to develop a Xamarin app for Android in VS 2015 (Enterprise). I have installed Xamarin on my computer however when I try to use any of the Xamarin functions they will not compile. This happens with all calls to Xamarin classes but lets look at one in particular.

When I try to use `ExportRenderer` it says the type or namespace cannot be found. However, I have `using Xamarin.Forms` in my using directives but VS complains it is never used even with all the calls to functions that should come from `Xamarin.Forms`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you download the other required components via the Android SDK Manager?

Comment: I had/have the android sdk, I am downloading and installing the other recommended packages now. Is there something specific I need for Xamarin dependencies?

Comment: Is Xamarin.Forms in your references without the yellow icon? Is it all of the projects in the solution that have the issue?

Comment: I went to NuGet and rolled back Xamarin.Forms to 2.1.0.6526 from 2.1.0.6529 which fixed this problem. Thank you guys for your help =]

Comment: try to update Xamarin.forms  version ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to use NuGet to roll back Xamarin.Forms from 2.1.0.6529 to 2.1.0.6526